# 3 sets of wire in a switch box

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I'm replacing a switch in my room, the old 2 way switch had all 3 blacks in the switch and the grounds bundled up and the whites bundled together I bought a 3 way switch I guess not knowing what I bought lol. Anyway I bundled the grounds and tied them into the switch and I'm trying to figure out where I'm supposed to put my blacks on the switch. Without killing power to my outlets when I turn my lights off.

Comment: A three way switch is basically a two way with an extra terminal, just use the two same-side terminals and ignore the extra.

Comment: And this why it is useful to label wires (with a bit of electrical tape) when taking things apart...

Answer (score 7):

1. identify where each of the three blacks goes.
2. wire-nut the black from the breaker to the black going to the outlets, along with a pigtail connected to the switch common (usually at the end of the switch with only one terminal).  That will give the outlets power all the time.
3. connect the black feeding the lights to either of the remaining terminals.  It doesn't matter which one, except one will have the lights on when the switch is up and the other when it's down.  Up for on is standard.

(If you find you're getting no power to either the lights or the outlets, swap the wires around until you get what you want.  As long as you're connecting only black wires, you should be safe.)